# Unknown host 'android-sdk.is.com'. You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle. Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project

Tags: gradle, proxy

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDWGL.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIOGY.png)

Unknown host 'android-sdk.is.com'. You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle.
Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project

how to solve this

Comment: are you working behind a company proxy?